# how to install gem acts_as_reviewable in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I try install gem 'acts_as_reviewable' in my project.
In my Gemfile

```
gem 'acts_as_reviewable'
#gem 'acts_as_reviewable', github: 'edshadi/acts_as_reviewable'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
acts_as_reviewable (0.0.1)
```

After 'bundle install'

When to generate reviewable

```
rails g acts_as_reviewable_migration
#or
rails g review:acts_as_reviewable_migration
```

So error:

> Could not find generator 'review:acts_as_reviewable_migration'. Maybe
>   you meant 'acts_as_reviewable_migration', 'active_record:migration' or
>   'acts_as_commentable_upgrade_migration' Run `rails generate --help`
>   for more options

When i run

```
rails g --help
#=>
ActsAsReviewableMigration:
  acts_as_reviewable_migration
```

So, how to fix this error.
And please recommend to me a gem same gem reviewable, can use it in rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this gem is compatible for Rails 4+:

https://github.com/edshadi/acts_as_reviewable/blob/master/acts_as_reviewable.gemspec#L15

Plus, it really looks unmaintained.

EDIT: You seem to have installed another version of `acts_as_reviewable`, the one from [ericsteen](https://github.com/ericsteen/acts_as_reviewable), whereas you previously had the one from [edshadi](https://github.com/edshadi/acts_as_reviewable). I would suggest trying to reinstall that one (via the `github` tag, not via rubygems).

Comment: pls recommend me a gem reviewable can use in rails 4

Comment: I don't see any to be honest, but see my edit above.

Comment: You mean: add 
`gem 'acts_as_reviewable', github: 'edshadi/acts_as_reviewable'`
I try this but dont work

Comment: I want to install gem at [link]https://github.com/ericsteen/acts_as_reviewable)  but 
when run `rails g --help`
error `Could not find acts_as_reviewable-0.0.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Comment: Did you do a `bundle install` in the meantime?

Comment: I run `bundle install` so display `.../acts_as_reviewable-79910ada7b59/acts_as_reviewable.gemspec is not valid. The validation error was 'authors may not be empty'`